# I used MediaQuery.of(context) but it has render overflow error on small screen

Tags: flutter, mobile

here is the snippet and I used mediaQuery class to resolve render overflow problem, but there the error can you tell me how to solve it

```
Container(
        padding: AppTheme.navbarPadding,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.11,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.94,
        decoration: AppTheme.navbarDecoration,
        child: Container(
          decoration: AppTheme.navbarElementDecoration,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
              elevation: 30,
              showSelectedLabels: false,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              currentIndex: screen,
              onTap: updateScreen,
              iconSize: AppTheme.navbarIconSize,
              selectedIconTheme:
                  const IconThemeData(color: AppTheme.selectedIconColor),
              unselectedIconTheme:
                  const IconThemeData(color: AppTheme.unselectedIconColor),
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              unselectedItemColor: AppTheme.unselectedNavbarColor,
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: const Icon(FeatherIcons.zap),
                  label: '',
                  activeIcon: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: AppTheme.navbarIconWidth,
                    height: AppTheme.navbarIconHeight,
                    decoration: AppTheme.navbarIconDecoration,
                    child: const Icon(
                      FeatherIcons.zap,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),`
```

This is the code that I used

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kri0.png)

Comment: Thank you, I resolve my problem by changing all inner fixed sizes to media query class.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height of the container,to match with the icon size

```
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,//change like this should match the height of the icon
```

Comment: That affect on large screen mobile

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the inner container uses the constraints of the outer container. when you use relative size with MediaQuery.of(context)  On a larger screen, the outer container becomes larger, and as the screen size decreases, the outer container size becomes smaller. But your inner container size is fixed. That's why it causes overflow issues.

I think the best option is to make the outer container's height and width also fixed. Because it no need to add responsiveness in that case,